# Using a for loop to access Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I want to call a function `Christian.exe` to the command line to act of a series of files that are indexed as "reentrant_008.sif" (8 is an example number).

`"Christian.exe reentrant_00" & num & ".sif reentrant_00" & num & ".pgm" 0 2000` is the text that needs to be fed into the command prompt for the program to execute (num is an arbitrary number)

There are approximately 400 files, so I want to create a vbs code that calls the command prompt for each file until all the files have been accessed so far this is my code:

```
For
Dim cmdpath
num = CStr(i)

Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")

If i < 10 Then
    cmdpath = "Christian.exe reentrant_00" & num & ".sif reentrant_00" & num & ".pgm" 0 2000
Else

    If i < 100 Then
        cmdpath = "Christian.exe reentrant_0" & num & ".sif reentrant_0" & num & ".pgm" 0 2000
    Else
        cmdpath = "Christian.exe reentrant_" & num & ".sif reentrant_" & num & ".pgm" 0 2000
    End If

End If

wshshell.run cmdpath

Next
```

Problem is that a new command prompt is being called for each file, which is slowing down my computer. How do I ensure that only one command window that addresses all my files is called?

Comment: I didnt notice at first but next time please include a complete code sample. You are missing a `For` as there is a lonely `Next`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, fixed!
I'm also having a minor issue with error handling. The files in the folder I'm analyzing aren't sequentially labeled (jumps from 12 to 14, 34 to 36, etc) 
So when I run my for loop sometimes an error message pops up since the program cannot find the file since it doesn't exists
When this happens I have to click the abort button for the program to resume - anyway to suppress the error messages so I can let the program run without an user?

Comment: Please don't move the target. Post new questions as new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) for `Run` you will see two option arguments `[intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn]`. If you want your EXE to wait before proceeding on the script change your call to this

```
wshshell.run cmdpath, 0, True
```

Where `0` will hide the window and `True` will wait for the program to finish before proceeding in the script. Depending on your needs you could change the number or remove it.

```
wshshell.run cmdpath,, True
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with both [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) and [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) I'm adding a PowerShell solution:

```psh
foreach ($i in 1..400) {
  $num = "{0:d3}" -f $i
  & Christian.exe "reentrant_${num}.sif" "reentrant_${num}.pgm" 0 2000
}
```

`&` is the call operator. I recommend using it whenever you run external commands in PowerShell, because otherwise you'll be in for a surprise when you try to run a command from a variable for the first time:

```
$christian = "Christian.exe"
$christian ...          # <-- throws an error, because $christian contains a
                        #     string, which is NOT automagically interpreted
                        #     as a command by PowerShell
& $christian ...        # <-- works
```

`-f` is the formatting operator, that allows you to create formatted string output. Since your command lines only differ by the zero-padding of the input and output files it's better to build the file names with pre-padded number strings.

I recommend doing the pre-padding in VBScript as well:

```vbs
For i = 1 To 400
  num = Right("000" & i, 3)
  cmdpath = "Christian.exe reentrant_" & num & ".sif reentrant_" & num & _
            ".pgm" 0 2000
  wshshell.run cmdpath, 0, True
Next
```

Comment: please make it Right.